Understanding a hint from Coxeter
The following problem posed in Coxeter and Greitzer's Geometry Revisited is readily proved by angle chasing (stick angles at $A,B$, chase). I am seeking the proof indicated by the author's hint on this problem, which appears to be distinct from an angle-chasing approach.
Problem 3.2.8: "Let two opposite sides of a cyclic quadrangle be extended to meet at $V$ and $W$. Then the internal bisectors of the angles at $V$ and $W$ are perpendicular." End-of-book hint: "Compare the arcs into which the circle is divided by the bisectors of the angles at $V$ and $W$." This hint seems to suggest focusing on arcs defined by $ILJK$ but I do not see how that leads to a proof.


We show $\overset{\frown}{IL} + \overset{\frown}{KJ} = \overset{\frown}{IK} + \overset{\frown}{LJ}$. This would imply that both equal $180^\circ$, hence that the desired angle is $90^\circ$.
Denote the equal angles at vertex $V$ by $\alpha$, and the angles at vertex $W$ by $\beta$.
We have that,
$\begin{align}
\overset{\frown}{IL} + \overset{\frown}{KJ} - \overset{\frown}{IK} - \overset{\frown}{LJ} &= \left( \overset{\frown}{IC} + \overset{\frown}{CL} \right) + \left( \overset{\frown}{KA} + \overset{\frown}{AJ} \right) - \left( \overset{\frown}{IB} + \overset{\frown}{BK} \right) - \left( \overset{\frown}{LD} + \overset{\frown}{DJ} \right) \\
&= \left( \overset{\frown}{IC} - \overset{\frown}{DJ} \right) + \left( \overset{\frown}{CL} - \overset{\frown}{BK} \right) + \left( \overset{\frown}{KA} - \overset{\frown}{LD} \right) + \left( \overset{\frown}{AJ} - \overset{\frown}{IB} \right) \\
&= (-2\alpha) \qquad + \qquad (2\beta) \qquad + \qquad (-2\beta) \qquad + \qquad (2\alpha) \\
&= 0
\end{align}$
hence the result. $\blacksquare$
P.S: If one does not want to deal with arc-angle calculations, an alternative way to prove this result can be as follows:

Quadrilateral $VDWB$ gives $\angle V + \angle W + \angle D = \angle B$, hence $\angle V + \angle W = 2\angle B - 180^\circ$.
Quadrilateral $VXWB$ gives $\angle X + \angle V/2 + \angle W/2 = \angle B$, hence $\angle X = \angle B - \angle V/2 - \angle W/2 = \boxed{90^\circ}$.

